# undefined symbol: lwgeom_sfcgal_version

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I'm currently trying to install PostGIS. I already have PostgreSQL installed, and I've followed [this link](https://geonode.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/tutorials/admin/install/install_postgis.html) (except I changed the geos version to 3.5.0 and postgis to 2.2.2) down to the final step which is to log into the template database and run "create extension postgis;". Doing so produces the following error, and I can only find [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192650/postgis-broken-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade) link which does not apply to me as everything is freshly installed today, and as per the [linked tutorial](https://geonode.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/tutorials/admin/install/install_postgis.html) I did build from the source, too.

Doing so produces this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.2.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.2.so: undefined symbol: lwgeom_sfcgal_version
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Additionally:

```
jack@jack-VirtualBox:~$ apt-file search liblwgeom
liblwgeom-2.2-5: /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.2.so.5
liblwgeom-2.2-5: /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.2.so.5.0.0
liblwgeom-2.2-5: /usr/share/doc/liblwgeom-2.2-5/NEWS.Debian.gz
liblwgeom-2.2-5: /usr/share/doc/liblwgeom-2.2-5/changelog.Debian.gz
liblwgeom-2.2-5: /usr/share/doc/liblwgeom-2.2-5/copyright
liblwgeom-2.2-5: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/liblwgeom-2.2-5
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/include/liblwgeom.h
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/include/liblwgeom_topo.h
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/lib/liblwgeom.a
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/lib/liblwgeom.so
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/share/doc/liblwgeom-dev/NEWS.Debian.gz
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/share/doc/liblwgeom-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
liblwgeom-dev: /usr/share/doc/liblwgeom-dev/copyright

jack@jack-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install liblwgeom-dev
[sudo] password for jack: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
liblwgeom-dev is already the newest version (2.2.2+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 248 not to upgrade.
```

Does anybody know what the cause of this error is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to rebuild once again ? Like explained on gis.stackexchange link provided in your post ?

I also did a fresh postgresql install with a fresh build of postgis :
*ubuntu 16.04, postgresql 9.5, postgis 2.2.2;

+libraries : GEOS 3.5.0, PROJ.4 4.9.2, GDAL 2.1.1, JSON-C 0.12.1, libwml2 2.9.4;*

and got stuck for a minute by the same problem. Then I found and followed the links in your post and after rebuilding postgis things work.